# Python printed output from IF statement to SQL column

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Is it possible that a printed output from an `if` statement can be placed in a MySQL column? That column num insert the value: "you have to pay 5% taxes" or "you not have to pay taxes".

```
num = 10
if 5 <= num <= 15:
    print ("you have to pay 5% taxes")
else:
    print ("you not have to pay taxes")

cursor.execute(""
SELECT *, FROM Customers
""")
```

Comment: Stuff you print goes to the console (standard output), to store something in a database, you may want to keep it in a variable and pass it to a script that updates the database. Have you looked at SQL `update` at all? Have a look at some online tutorials about updating tables and give it a try - your code only shows you printing text and selecting all columns from a table (with a typo)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [**MySQL**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html) database with python.

```
num    = 15
string = "you have to pay 5% taxes" if 5<=n<=15 else "you not have to pay taxes"

sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = (num, string)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
print(string)
```